# electron setSize with animation not working

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using this code to resize my electron window on OSX:

```
document.getElementById("resize-btn2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.setSize(1024, 786, animate);
});
```

It is working fine (the resizing) but if I try to use the "animate" argument I get an error in the console:

> animate is not defined

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md), animate is an optional argument that need to be a Boolean:

> win.setSize(width, height[, animate])
>
> - width Integer
> - height Integer
> - animate Boolean (optional) macOS
>
> Resizes the window to width and height.

You are passing a variable named `animate` as an argument, and I guess that you don't have it defined anywhere, hence the error.

The same way `width` and `height` are Integers and you pass Integers, `animate` being a boolean you have to pass `true` or `false`:

```
window.setSize(1024, 786, true);
// or
window.setSize(1024, 786, false);
```

depending if you want animation or not, applicable only to `macOS`, as the documentation says.

Comment: Jorge, thank you for the excellent explanation! I have learned something trival for experienced developers but crucial for beginners like me – simply how to interprete that part of the documentation. I was not aware what the brackets are meaning and also about the bolean! So, many tnahks!

Comment: @SandorRozsa haha, nice :-)